# Type error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element about_window.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my code. All I did is that I changed the texts in the about window in all layouts file and I find this error in the xml file.

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
> - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-

also in the src files the error is "R cannot be resolved to a variable". This is my the XML code:

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="none" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6.0dip"
        android:text="xxxxxx"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="14.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:text="@string/app_version_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
        android:text="xxxxx"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="14.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:text="xxxxxxx"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="14.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/dev_email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="youss.boss1dev@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="#2704fc"
        android:textSize="14.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                      android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="110.0dip"
            android:layout_height="44.0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip"
            android:text="xxxx" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where are declarations: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`?

Comment: you mean this :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

Comment: Then update your question with whole xml code where you have an error

Comment: I did The error is in this line :

Comment: <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the perfect Layout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6.0dip"
            android:text="xxxxxx"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:text="app_version_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:text="xxxxx"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:text="xxxxxxx"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14.0dip"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dev_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="youss.boss1dev@gmail.com"
            android:textColor="#2704fc"
            android:textSize="14.0dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close_btn"
                android:layout_width="110.0dip"
                android:layout_height="44.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip"
                android:text="xxxx"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: when I past this this is the new error :error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xmlns' in package 'android'

Comment: Delete android:xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from both linear layout

Comment: Yeeah Duuude Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view ends with a /> finishing the object, I think childrem will not have access to the tags android.

All your views are closed by itself (with "/>"). So your document doesnt have a root, only a list.

Also: Childs doesnt needs to declare xmlns again, such the second object:
    android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
That also has a typo with android twice.

Also:
Do any text contains > or < ? It should be added into the strings.xml so those characters can appear

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `LinearLayout`:

`android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

it should be:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

you typed twice `android`. Instead removing just `android` remove whole line you don't need it because you already have declaration in `ScrollView` Actually the problem is `ScrollView` can contain only one direct child and you have multiple. So you have to put all your xml code below `ScrollView` in one container either `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.

Comment: I did it Always the same prob :(

Comment: See the answer now